# New to assembly. How to count number of characters in argument passed?

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

I'm very new to assembly, so please forgive me if this is rather trivial. For the following command:

```
$ ./prog1 *string*
```

where *string* is the argument passed and is some sequence of characters (but no spaces), how would I go about finding the number of characters in *string* ? What I want prog1 to do is to simply output exactly what is typed, including a newline character. For example:

```
$ ./prog1 helloworld
```

would simply output "helloworld" and a newline. So far, my code does print out the input, but I need to give the actual number of characters to the %edx register so it will print correctly, otherwise I have to hard code the number of characters myself.

```
.globl _start



_start:

movl $4,%eax

movl $1,%ebx

movl 4(%esp),%ecx     ; <--- save argument to %ecx register

movl $100, %edx       ; <--- need to know exactly how many characters in argument to %edx register

int $0x80



#Exit

movl $1,%eax

movl $0,%ebx

int $0x80
```

My idea was to use an accumulator and loop through *string*, to count the number of characters byte by byte until I hit the null terminator. But how exactly is this done in GAS?

Comment: Once you have a pointer to `argv[1]`, then the problem is to implement the C function `strlen`.  Google that and you'll find plenty of examples of finding the first `0` byte to find the length of a 0-terminated C-style string.

Comment: And BTW, the right terminology for your comment is "*load* `argv[0]` to %ecx register".  Copying data from memory is a load, copying *to* memory is a store.  In this case, ECX is temporary scratch space for a pointer that you're going to increment, so "save" isn't the right terminology.  You want to load the pointer into a reg so you can do stuff with it.

Comment: You probably want to load `8(%esp)`, the first arg *after* the program name, and after `argc`.  See [x86 Linux assembler get program parameters from \_start](//stackoverflow.com/q/16721164) and the i386 System V ABI (which defines the process startup environment.)

Answer (score 2):

In nasm you can try that:

```
    section .text
    global _start

    _start:
            push ebp
            mov ebp, esp

            mov ebx, [ebp+12]
            cmp ebx, 0x00
            jz exit
            mov eax, ebx

    compare:

            cmp byte [eax], 0x00
            jz print
            inc eax
            jmp compare 

    print:
            sub eax, ebx ; now eax have the len of the string in argv[1]


    exit:
            mov eax, 0x1
            mov ebx, 0x0
            int 0x80
```

i'm new to asm too, but i hope to help

Comment: This is pretty good, but `push ebp` to make a stack frame in `_start` doesn't really make sense.  EBP on entry to `_start` holds garbage.  (Or in a static binary, holds zero on Linux, because the kernel zeros registers to avoid leaking kernel data before entering user-space.)  The i386 System V ABI recommends that if you're going to do stack frames, you should NULL-terminate the linked list by pushing a 0 as the first saved-EBP value.  e.g. `push 0` / `mov ebp, esp` so EBP points at the 0, for any functions you call from `_start`.  But yes, after you push, `argv[1]` is at ESP/EBP+12.

Comment: You'd normally want to write a loop with a `jnz` at the bottom, instead of a jmp at the bottom and conditional break inside.  [Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](//stackoverflow.com/q/47783926)/.  Like maybe check the first byte outside the loop with cmp/jz (because strings can be zero length with `./a.out ''`), then `inc eax` / `cmp byte [eax], 0` / `jnz compare` as the loop body.